# Docusign eSignature REST API doesn't give error when the email provided does not exist

Tags: docusignapi

I am using the sample code provided by docusign, but there is no indication in response if the envelope is actually sent or not.
If the email does not exists, it still generates the envelope id and there is no error.
here's the response:

````
Please enter the signer's name: saf
Please enter the cc email address: scisaif1@gmail.com
Please enter the cc name: saif
{'bulk_envelope_status': None,
 'envelope_id': 'bd7781a5-ea9e-472d-b087-90baa12b573f',
 'error_details': None,
 'recipient_signing_uri': None,
 'recipient_signing_uri_error': None,
 'status': 'sent',
 'status_date_time': '2022-08-14T10:02:02.9400000Z',
 'uri': '/envelopes/bd7781a5-ea9e-472d-b087-90baa12b573f'}
Your envelope has been sent.```

this is the response when email does not exist, i get an email that says 
Documents you sent for electronic signature could not be delivered to this email address: adfasasdfasdgasddf@gmail.com
````

Comment: Probably not a question that can be answered on SO. Better to contact the vendor and ask them about the intended workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The internet email system is a weak creature. If DocuSign receives a negative delivery report, then the envelope status will be updated. (Try a bad email on the DocuSign web app.)

But there are bad email addresses that don't result in a negative report to DocuSign.

For these cases, the envelope's expiration tells you that there was no response.

I suggest that you ask the signers for both their email and sms mobile number. DocuSign can then deliver the signing invite to both.

Answer (score 1):

Suggest you use [DocuSign Connect](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/webhooks/connect/) and set a [webhook](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/webhooks/). This will give you an event if email bounced, or opened. You can use these events to decide what to do in your system.